# How to configure RTL (Right to Left) support in Material UI version 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I updated my app to `Material-UI` version 5 from version 4 and the RTL support is not working anymore.

I looked at the docs and followed each of the steps:

https://mui.com/guides/right-to-left/

**The actual result** is the application is still LTR (You can look at the `TextField` component in the Codesandbox link below).

**The expected result** is the app should be RTL.

And still, The RTL support is not working.

In addition, I created an example version in `Codesandbox` :

https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-with-rtl-in-material-ui-v5-jtii6?file=/src/index.js

I'll appreciate your help in finding what is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work for you? v4 and v5 RTL `TextField`s look the same to me.

Comment: You can look at the Codesandbox that I added. The label of TextField is LTR instead of RTL.

Comment: The label from v4 is on the left too, only the placeholder is on the right. So you want both of them on the right too, right?

Comment: Yes. I want to set RTL globally in my application.

Comment: hi i have the same problem here. any solution ?

Comment: This link is helpful and can show you the configs that you need to make your mui rtl. `https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/right-to-left/`

Answer (score 21):

I had this problem using Persian language. But it's answer is too easy. you just need some simple steps.
My Example environment is:

1. "react": "^18.2.0"
2. "react-dom": "^18.2.0"

Lets do it:

Step 1: install below packages (I give you exact versions to be sure it works in case of future updates):

- "@emotion/react": "^11.9.3"
- "@emotion/styled": "^11.9.3"
- "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4"
- "@mui/material": "^5.9.1"
- "stylis": "^4.1.1"
- "stylis-plugin-rtl": "^2.1.1"

hint: this is my package.json file:

[image]

Step 2: Change direction of html tag in public/index.html like this:

```
`<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">`
```

Step 3: Add below section in index.js file:

3-1 : required imports:

```
import {createTheme, ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';
import {prefixer} from 'stylis';
import {CacheProvider} from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
```

3-2 : required cache:

```
const cacheRtl = createCache({
   key: 'muirtl',
   stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin],
});
```

3-3 : required theme:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  direction: 'rtl',
});
```

3-4: This is Final Step in which you wrap two wrapper around your  component like this:

```
<CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <App/>
  </ThemeProvider>
</CacheProvider>
```

Finally, your completed index.js file should be exactly like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {createTheme, ThemeProvider} from '@mui/material/styles';
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';
import {prefixer} from 'stylis';
import {CacheProvider} from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';

const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: 'muirtl',
  stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin],
});
const theme = createTheme({
  direction: 'rtl',
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <App/>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </CacheProvider>
);
```

Now your Entire application is rtl. I show you an persian example with images to see this:

Change your App.jsx component like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Autocomplete, Box, TextField} from "@mui/material";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Box m={2}>
      <Autocomplete
        sx={{width: 300}}
        options={iranStates}
        onChange={(event, value) => console.log(value)}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={"لیست استانها"}/>}/>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default App;

const iranStates = [
  "آذربایجان شرقی",
  "آذربایجان غربی",
  "اردبیل",
  "اصفهان",
  "البرز",
  "ایلام",
  "بوشهر",
  "تهران",
  "چهارمحال و بختیاری",
]
```

and see the result:

[image]

Comment: Your code is totally true but i wish you explain more about your code and configs

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to handle this issue! I eventually used `document.dir` + all of MUI's docs instructions.

Here's my code live in CodeSandbox (it toggles direction + MUI language + date-pickers + theme-mode):
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/quizzical-zhukovsky-lvq2fs?file=%2Fsrc%2FSupportedLocales.ts%3A10%2C33

I wrote a very long article about it: https://medium.com/@itayperry91/react-and-mui-change-muis-theme-mode-direction-and-language-including-date-pickers-ad8e91af30ae

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For MUI 5 need to `import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';` and `import createCache from '@emotion/cache';`

Here's the code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from 'tss-react/mui';
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import createCache from '@emotion/cache';
import rtlPlugin from 'stylis-plugin-rtl';
import { prefixer } from 'stylis';

const isBrowser = typeof document !== 'undefined';
let insertionPoint;

if (isBrowser) {
  const emotionInsertionPoint = document.querySelector(
    'meta[name="emotion-insertion-point"]',
  );
  insertionPoint = emotionInsertionPoint ?? undefined;
}

const cacheRTL = createCache({
  key: 'mui-style-rtl',
  stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin],
  insertionPoint,
});

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext(undefined);

function ThemeWrapper(props) {
  const theme = useState({
    direction: 'rtl' 
  });
  const muiTheme = createTheme(theme);
  const { children } = props;

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cacheRTL}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
        <div>
          <ThemeContext.Provider>
            {children}
          </ThemeContext.Provider>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
}

export default ThemeWrapperMapped;
```

Here's the implementation in my project https://github.com/ilhammeidi/dandelion-starter/blob/master/app/containers/App/ThemeWrapper.js